# How to receive tcp connection data in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

My previous Project is developed with jsxmlsocket(https://www.developerfusion.com/project/18979/jsxmlsocket). It is working with flash. Js xml socket connected with ip and port then The response like this {"ClientID":"202.75.xx.xxx:xxxxx","ServerDist":"1"} By using this client id i am sending vehicle device id, So i am getting all the vehicle information continously.

But now i am working in PHP Sockets i am getting Client id and ServerDist, After sednig ClientID with device id i am not getting correct client information again i am getting ClientID and ServerDist So can you please help me how to get the device data

```
<?php

$message = json_encode(["ClientID" => $ClientID, 'LanguageType' => 'en-us', "TrackSystemNos" => '1399288XXXX|']);

if (socket_send($socket, $message, strlen($message), 0)) {
    echo "Message send successfully \n" . $message . '<br/>';
    sleep(2);

    while (true) {
        echo socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 9204, 0, $host, $port);
        echo "Received $buf from remote address $fhost and remote port $fport" . PHP_EOL;
        sleep(2);
    }
}
```

I need response like this:

```
{
   "SimID":"139928XXXXX",
   "SignalType":"Locate",
   "DateTime":"2019-10-24 13:31:40",
   "Longitude1":"0.00000",
   "Latitude1":"0.00000",
   "Longitude":"0.00000",
   "Latitude":"0.00000",
   "Velocity":"0",
   "Angle":"0",
   "LocateStatus":"NoLocate",
   "AccStatus":"OFF",
   "Temperature":"0",
   "Oil":"0",
   "Oil2":"0",
   "LevelNum":"12.13",
   "OilIn":"0",
   "OilOut":"0",
   "Miles":"7611669",
   "ParkingSpan":"1.11:54:59",
   "TodayMile":"61321"
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code you're using and where you think the issue is?

Comment: $message = json_encode(["ClientID" => $ClientID,  'LanguageType' => 'en-us',  "TrackSystemNos" => '1399288XXXX|']);
    if (socket_send($socket, $message, strlen($message), 0)) {
        echo "Message send successfully \n" . $message . '<br/>';
        sleep(2);
     while (true) {
            echo socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 9204, 0, $host, $port);
            echo "Received $buf from remote address $fhost and remote port $fport" . PHP_EOL;
            sleep(2);
        }
    }

Comment: I Need response like This
{
   "SimID":"139928XXXXX",
   "SignalType":"Locate",
   "DateTime":"2019-10-24 13:31:40",
   "Longitude1":"0.00000",
   "Latitude1":"0.00000",
   "Longitude":"0.00000",
   "Latitude":"0.00000",
   "Velocity":"0",
   "Angle":"0",
   "LocateStatus":"NoLocate",
   "AccStatus":"OFF",
   "Temperature":"0",
   "Oil":"0",
   "Oil2":"0",
   "LevelNum":"12.13",
   "OilIn":"0",
   "OilOut":"0",
   "Miles":"7611669",
   "ParkingSpan":"1.11:54:59",
   "TodayMile":"61321"
}